# Change CodeMirror Placeholder via JS

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I'm using CodeMirror version 5.51 along with the placeholder [addon](https://codemirror.net/demo/placeholder.html).
The placeholder itself is set like this.

```
<textarea id="code" class="hidden" placeholder="Paste your XML here..."></textarea>
```

When the user now changes the website's language, I would like to change the placeholder's text as well.

I've tried setting the placeholder directly

```
this.$editor.options.placeholder = "New value"
```

but this does not take effect immediately.

Is there a way to

1. Specify a function that returns the string instead of a string directly?
2. Re-initialize the placeholder through a function call?

The addon's [code](https://codemirror.net/addon/display/placeholder.js) suggest that you can use something else than a string but I could not find more information on that subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`cm.setOption()`](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#setOption) method to programmatically update the placeholder text, i.e.:

```
this.$editor.setOption('placeholder', 'New value');
```

Here is a proof-of-concept example:

```js
const editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
  lineNumbers: true
});

document.getElementById('update-placeholder-text').addEventListener('click', () => {
  editor.setOption('placeholder', document.getElementById('placeholder-text').value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.54.0/codemirror.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.54.0/addon/display/placeholder.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.54.0/codemirror.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input type="text" id="placeholder-text" value="Lorem ipsum" /><button id="update-placeholder-text">Update placeholder text</button>
<hr />
<textarea id="code" name="code" placeholder="Code goes here..."></textarea>
```

Comment: Calling setOption() does not refresh the UI directly. CodeMirror will consider the value on the next refresh though.

Comment: Your code works in combination with the button click. It does not work without the button though. I'm changing the placeholder in the mounted() function of my vue app. This happens before any user interaction.

Comment: My code is simply a proof-of-concept how the `setOption()` works: not sure how is that lost on you since I've explicitly stated as such. If you invoke `this.$editor.setOption('placeholder', 'New value');` I don't see why it will not work

Answer (score 0):

After a little while of tinkering, I found that the following two lines do the trick.

The first line internally sets the new value while the second one (obviously) overrides the current UI representation.

```
this.$editor.options.placeholder = "Value";
this.$editor.state.placeholder.innerText = "Value";
```

The first line (I assume) is equal to what @Terry suggested.

```
this.$editor.setOptions('placeholder', 'New value');
```